# Python Count each email on each page of PDF file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

I am trying to count each string that has @twitter or @facebook on this pdf file with 1537 pages. I initialized a counter that goes off each time the page finds an @twitter or @facebook but the counter is just counting the amount of pages instead of the amounts of emails that contain facebook or twitter. I am using python 3 and importing pdftotext to read the file.
here is the code

```
import pdftotext
count = 0
# 1 read the pdf
with open('Users.pdf', 'rb') as f:
    pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f)

# loop thru pages
for page in pdf:
    if '@facebook' in page or '@twitter' in page:
        count += 1


print(count)
```

the output:

```
1537
```

which is the amount of pages the file has

Comment: Hey man, are you sure that the `page` inside de loop holds the content of the PDF pages?
Maybe you need to call another method before trying to count the strings you are looking for.

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what you told it to. For every page, no matter how many times the strings you're looking for appear, you're incrementing count by one. Seems like regex matching would work better; check it out here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [manny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8933990/manny) you should use regex matching to achieve what you want to do.

```
import pdftotext
import re

count = 0
# 1 read the pdf
with open('Users.pdf', 'rb') as f:
    pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f)

# regex pattern
pattern = '@facebook|@twitter'

# loop thru pages
for page in pdf:
    count += len(re.findall(pattern, page))

print(count)
```

To check and try your regex pattern, I recommend [Regex101](https://regex101.com/).